# Require a file inside a factory using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, requirejs, factory

I've tried to require a file inside my factory and receive a error. Then I've decided to use RequireJS framework and, now, I'm having another problem.

**Main.js**

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    'var1': './models/var1'
  }
});

require( ['./controllers/mainApp'] );
```

**MainApp.js:**

```
var app = angular.module('mainApp', []); 

app.factory('varFactory', ['var1', function(var1){
  console.log( var1 );

    return '';
}]);
```

**index.ejs**

```
<html ng-app='mainApp'>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title> Teste </title>
        <script data-main="./public/Main.js" src="./public/javascripts/require.js"></script>
        <script src="./public/javascripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>...</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm using node.js and express.js to control my routes and my server. 
When I'm trying to access the index.ejs, i'm getting the error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr]    
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/unpr?p0=var1Provider%20%3C-%20var1%20%3C-%20varFactory
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:3000/public/javascripts/angular.min.js:6:417
    ...
```

I'm doing something really wrong, but I don't know how to require some file inside my factory varFactory. I'm trying to use RequireJS, but I guess I'm doing it in the stupid way.

Somebody can help me?
[Sorry for my bad english :P]

Comment: Do you know javascript modularity and angularjs modularity. here var1 is angularjs javascript module. create service or factory by using var1.

Comment: When I put something inside the path in the config, he understands that this something is a module? I can not put, for example, a model within the path?

Comment: Wait few minutes and try to this is the simple example. http://marcoslin.github.io/angularAMD/#/home